# Retrofit URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: android, retrofit

I've created a method to delete a certain data in MySQL database using Retrofit2, but it always throws an error like this :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "apicall=deleteBooking&={id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query. for method UserService.deleteBooking
```

Here is my deleteBooking method :

```
public void deleteBooking(int id){
        Call<BookingInfo> call = userService.deleteBooking(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BookingInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BookingInfo> call, Response<BookingInfo> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i("DELETE RESPONSE: ", response.body().toString());
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BookingInfo> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("DELETE ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my UserService interface :

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET("api.php?apicall=getBookings")
    Call<GetBookingInfo> getBookings();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api.php?apicall=createBooking")
    Call<BookingInfo> addBooking(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> booking);

    @PUT("api.php?apicall=updateStatus")
    Call<BookingInfo> updateStatus(@Path("status") String status, @Body BookingInfo booking);

    @DELETE("api.php?apicall=deleteBooking&={id}")
    Call<BookingInfo> deleteBooking(@Query("id") int id);

}
```

I have changed the call deleteBooking to @Query (i've searched a few questions in and the answer is always have to change to @Query, and before that i use @Path), but it still throws the error. I don't know the solution for this. If you want more info feel free to ask and i will give you your needed code, etc. Thank you!

Comment: remove this &={id}

Comment: remove  '&={id}' from @DELETE annottation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to below:

```
@DELETE("api.php")
Call<BookingInfo> deleteBooking(@Query("id") int id,
                                @Query("apicall") String action);
```

and call it like below:

```
Call<BookingInfo> call = userService.deleteBooking(id, "deleteBooking");
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to move the action out, try this:

```
     @DELETE("api.php?apicall=deleteBooking")
     Call<BookingInfo> deleteBooking(@Query("id") int id);
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit of abstracting the action out. Delete operation will always have deleteBooking action.

Comment: you need to do that because you are passing it as a query paramter.
If you control the backend as well, you can modify the api endpoint to something like : "api.php?id=1" if its always going to be delete

Comment: I am saying hardcoded deleteBooking in url is fine `@DELETE("api.php?apicall=deleteBooking")`